# Customizing parts in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents

In the screenshot blue, is it possible to replace the this ( I ) preceding the name of the part by (Part I) ?!. 
[image]

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\addtocontents{toc}{\smallskip \hrule height 3pt \vspace{-4.5ex} \vspace{0.2cm}  }
\part{Differential Forms}
\addtocontents{toc}{{ }}
\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{0.2cm} \nobreak\smallskip \hrule height 2.5pt }
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post compilable examples. And you had questions similar to this, with `tocloft` included. Using that package  it's quite to achieve this!

Comment: I didn’t understand what you mean by "compilable examples". Besides, this is a different question !

Comment: Your document is a fragment only. It misses `\end{document}`

Comment: I edited the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution with `titlesec` and `titletoc`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\titleformat{\part}[display]
  {\scshape\filcenter}
  {\large\partname~\thepart}
  {2ex}
  {\Large}
  [\vspace{5ex}]

\titlecontents{part}[0pt]
  {\bfseries\protect\addvspace{15pt}\titlerule[1pt]\addvspace{1.2ex}}
  {}
  {\color{RoyalBlue}\partname~}%numbered, unnumbered
  {\hfill\contentspage}
  [\addvspace{0.7ex}{\titlerule[1pt]}\addvspace{1.5ex}]

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{Beginnings}

\section{Things}

\section{More Things}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use `tocloft` for example and redefine `\cftpartpresnum` to contain the word `Part` (or whatever `\partname` yields). In order to prevent clashes with the part number, increase the width of the number box with `\addtolength{\cftpartnumwidth}{20pt}` (The value of `20pt` is just a guess, nothing more!)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand{\cftpartpresnum}{\partname{} }
\addtolength{\cftpartnumwidth}{20pt}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\addtocontents{toc}{\smallskip \hrule height 3pt \vspace{-4.5ex} \vspace{0.2cm}  }
\part{Differential Forms}
\addtocontents{toc}{{ }}
\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{0.2cm} \nobreak\smallskip \hrule height 2.5pt }
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The indents of toc entries might have to be extended as well...